# Escaping a Dollar Sign in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

This wasn't a problem in 0.9.2, but in 0.10, when I try to access a key in a map that has a dollar sign in it, I get hammered with errors that I haven't defined the variable. Specifically:

```
blah = FOREACH meh GENERATE source, json_post_id#'$id' AS post_id;
```

returns

```
Undefined parameter : id
```

That's fine and makes sense, but when I amend it to:

```
blah = FOREACH meh GENERATE source, json_post_id#'\$id' AS post_id;
```

I get:

```
Unexpected character '$'
```

Ideas?

[Edit] Forgot to mention: have tried with 2 backslashes and 3 backslashes as well. No dice. [/Edit]

Comment: I have no idea if that works, but you could try with \\u0024...

Comment: strange, works for me in pig 0.10.0 without escaping: just m#'$id'. Are you sure the problem is not caused by something else?

Comment: @Eli It is also working for me on 0.10.0

Comment: Have you tried putting the `FOREACH` in a block as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670249/pig-problem-with-split-stringstrsplit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Based on a response to your Mail Archive Posting](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@pig.apache.org/msg06997.html), it looks like the behavior will be "different when using Grunt shell and running it as a script."

   > **Input file**
   >
   > ```
   > cheolsoo@localhost:~/workspace/pig-svn $cat 1.txt $id,a
   > ```
   >
   > **Grunt shell**
   >
   > The `$` with no backslash works:
   >
   > ```
   > grunt> A = LOAD '1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (k:chararray,
   > v:chararray); grunt> B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOMAP(k, v) AS M; grunt> C
   > = FOREACH B GENERATE M#'$id'; grunt> DUMP C; (a)
   > ```
   >
   > **Script**
   >
   > The `$` with a single backslash works:
   >
   > ```
   > cheolsoo@localhost:~/workspace/pig-svn $cat test.pig A = LOAD '1.txt' 
   > USING PigStorage(',') AS (k:chararray, v:chararray); B = FOREACH A
   > GENERATE TOMAP(k, v) AS M; C = FOREACH B GENERATE M#'\$id'; DUMP C;
   >
   > cheolsoo@localhost:~/workspace/pig-svn $./bin/pig -x local test.pig
   > (a)
   > ```
2. Also, from [Pig problem with split string(STRSPLIT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670249/pig-problem-with-split-stringstrsplit), have you tried either of the following.

   - Correctly escaping the character `u0024`. Test single using single or double quotes to see if that makes a difference. [This answer shows that the single quote makes a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854861/1085891) which you have but it's worth mentioning.
   - Alternatively, although related, [break the loop into a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6832401/1085891).

     ```
     blah = FOREACH meh {
         GENERATE source, json_post_id#'$id' AS post_id; 
     }
     ```
3. It looks like you are concatenating an `id`. Make sure you are not suppose to be using `CONCAT()`. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#concat
4. [According to the `Class PigStorage` documentation (Pig 0.10.0 API)](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html):

   > A load function that parses a line of input into fields using a character delimiter. The default delimiter is a tab. You can specify any character as a literal ("a"), a known escape character ("\t"), or a dec or hex value ("\u001", "\x0A").

Comment: The first solution from Cheolsoo above is 100% correct. Strange and counterintuitive, but correct.