# How to replace '$' from string in pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

We know to replace word we can use REPLACE keyword like below...

```
RELATION = FOREACH data GENERATE REPLACE(string,'a','b');
```

above statement replace all 'a' letters to 'b'.

But if I want to REPLACE dollar sign($). then how I can do that? Because in Pig '$' indicates no of column. So for example, if want to replace '$' from string like '$1234.56' and want output like '1234.56'.

```
RELATION = FOREACH data GENERATE REPLACE(string,'$','');
```

But this not work for me.

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14269913/1927206

Comment: I am not getting solution from http://stackoverflow.com/q/14269913/1927206 . Can you please give example to replace '$' from string?

Comment: No. I know nothing of PIG.Can you update your question with the result of the suggestions. Have you tried specifying the $ in hex, octal, binary, some other way (you know the ones I mean). Documentation? Colleagues? Also remember it is the weekend, more people may see your question over the next couple of days, and you may be able to solve it yourself long before that if you try.

Answer (score 0):

Using Unicode:

```
    REPLACE(string,'\u0024','')
```

Comment: No Brian, it's not working. I also tried '\$', '\\$' and your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can helpful to look at the string regrexes in Java, for instance: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

In your particular case, you can use the following:

`REPLACE(string, '[$]', '')`

For increased flexibility, (when dealing with other currency types for instance), it might be a good idea to remove all non-numeric characters, except '.'. In that case use:

`REPLACE(string, '[^\\d.]', '')`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (triple backslashes)

```
REPLACE(string,'\\\$','')
```